# windows: read item from .txt and create empty file for each item found

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

please consider a input.txt file that containt this:

```
C0001.MXF
C0002.MXF
C0003.MXF
C0004.MXF
C0005.MXF
C0006.MXF
C0007.MXF
...
C9999.MXF
```

simply I would like do a batch that, for each CXXXX.MXF item create a empty file CXXXX.TXT in c:\folderD

thanks

Comment: You haven't asked a question. You have implied you are looking for a ready made script. But this site is for questions about programming. If you break down your requirement into distinct logical steps, you can probably google those steps and develop your own solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%f in (input.txt) do (copy nul c:\folderD\%%f /y > nul & @echo Creating File %%f )
```